# Phonegap IOS8 Open Setting(Location) page

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I read that on IOS8 you can now open Setting page via this code.

```
 - (void)openSettings
    {
        BOOL canOpenSettings = (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL);
        if (canOpenSettings) {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        }
    }
```

I am just wondering if there is any way to do it in Phonegap via those code?

Comment: create a plugin with that code or search for an existing one